# Help needed creating a test class

Tags: unit-test

I have just started using Salesforce and have created this class. I have created a button that exports the opportunity to a csv file. It took me a while to get my head around it but it now downloads the csv as I would like it.

My problem is I have no idea how to create a test class for it. I don't understand how to create a call to my exportCSV class. Any assisstance with this would be great thanks

```
    public with sharing class exportCSV {
        public string header{get;set;}
        public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
        public String rId {get;set;}
        public List<Opportunity> AllOpenOpportunities {get; private set;} 
        public exportCSV() {
            header = 'Acc_Ref__c,Purchase_Order_Number1__c,Position__c,Total_Hours_Required__c,Shift_Start_Date__c,Shift_End_Date__c,Number_of_Shifts__c,Hours_per_Shift__c,Shift_Time__c,Pay_Code__c,Opportunity_Unique_Reference__c\r';
            rId  = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer');
            Id currentRecordId = rId.right(15);
            AllOpenOpportunities = [SELECT id, Name, Acc_Ref__c, Purchase_Order_Number1__c, Position__c, Total_Hours_Required__c, Shift_Start_Date__c, Shift_End_Date__c,Number_of_Shifts__c,Hours_per_Shift__c,Shift_Time__c,Pay_Code__c, Opportunity_Unique_Reference__c
                        FROM Opportunity 
                        WHERE id =: currentRecordId];
}
```

}

Comment: [Getting Started with Apex Unit Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro)

Answer (score 1):

To start test class, you need to create all the required data, instantiate the class and call the methods of that class.

Following is the sample code to start Test class-

```
@isTest                    
public class TestClassOne {

    public static testMethod void testMethodOne() {
        // Create Account Data
        Account acc = new Account(Name='TestAcc');
        insert acc;

        // Create Opportunity Data
        Opportunity opp = new Oppportunity(Name='Test Opp', AccountId=acc.Id);
        insert opp;
        system.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('currentRecordId', opp.Id);
        exportCSV conObj = new exportCSV();
        Test.startTest();
        // Call Methods of the class
        conObj.methodOne();
        Test.stopTest();
        // Write assert statements
    }   
}
```

Along with this you can refere following links for Test Class:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm